# Any idea on how to pass a a clicked number from an array to another page without using forms in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, hyperlink, calculation

Any idea on how to pass a a clicked number from an array to another page without using forms in PHP?
I want to grab figures from the array and use it for calculations on the second page.

Comment: what's the problem with using a form? The ways to send data from one page to the other as the user navigates between them are either a) form data, or b) querystring data in the URL. But for an array, the querystring is generally not that great. You should perhaps give a bit more detail and explain your aversion to forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_GET` method.

Try, `<a href="another_page.php?value=myvalue" class='btn btn-default style-as-button'>My Button</a>`,

then on `another_page.php` check for `$_GET['value']`.

```
if (isset($_GET['value'])) {
 // do some logic
}
```

Comment: What about this snippet?

Comment: This is what I came up with and it worked just fine.

<?php //array of numbers $arr=range(1,10); //printing elements of array foreach ($arr as $x) { echo '<a href="next_page.php?x='.$x.'"><div>'.$x.'</div></a>'; }

?>

On the next page this is what you add

 <?php
  // Retrieve the URL variables from the previous page.
  $n = $_GET['x'];


 ?>

Comment: What’s the difference between your answer and mine? If I’m correct why not mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry  haron68, Your answer is very correct. Was just an oversight.

Comment: I see then, I suppose there’s some caveat to your question that it’s a $_GET in an array. I can edit my answer to reflect the nuances? Otherwise if it worked for you, you can accept it